# Nuxt app on AWS Amplify has routing issues after refresh in the browser

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, aws-amplify

I have a nuxt website deployed to AWS via Amplify. Here is my directory structure:

```
|pages
|_schedule
|__ _id
|_articles
|__ _id
```

If I refresh on the /articles page for example, Amp adds a backlash to the end (/articles/). After the refresh, when I click on one of the articles on the page, nothing happens. I'm using nuxt-link in the code.

Another issue I'm having is when I hit refresh on a /articles/ page. Amp again adds a backlash and then I am redirected to the root (this is with Amp's default rewrite rule of sending you to the root with a 404 rewrite.)

Here are my build settings:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
        - echo "API_URL=$API_URL" >> .env 
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run generate
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Here is my nuxt.config.js file:

```js
export default {
  target: 'static',
  
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    apiUrl: process.env.API_URL,
  },
  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
    },
  },

  head: {
    title: 'My title',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'preconnect', href: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com' },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href:
          'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@400;700;900&display=swap',
      },
    ],
  },

  components: true,
  buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios'],

  tailwindcss: {
    cssPath: '~/assets/css/tailwind.css',
    configPath: 'tailwind.config.js',
    exposeConfig: false,
    config: {},
  },
}
```

#### Update

I actually fixed the 1st issue. Previously I missed that  I had the following property in my nuxt.config.js file:

```js
router: {
  trailingSlash: false
},
```

Once I removed this, my first issue was fixed. I am able to refresh on /articles and click on links.

One thing I notice on my local is when I run nuxt generate then nuxt start, when I hit refresh on a page like /article/, the following happens in my network tab:
[image]

Those files are in dist/_nuxt folder which get created after running nuxt generate.

When I deploy to AWS Amplify and do the same thing, I get the following in the network tab:

[image]

As you can see, once deployed, it doesn't look for those js files. I'm thinking it has something to do with the redirect rules. Currently I don't have any. I've tried quite a few things already.

#### Update 2

I deployed my app to app.netlify.com/drop for testing: gracious-leavitt-e8523a.netlify.app

Below are details on the roster page and a player page:

Roster
Directory Structure

```
|pages
|_roster
|__index.vue
```

index.vue

```html
<template>
    <Roster></Roster>
</template>

<script>
import Roster from "~/components/Roster.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        Roster
    },
}
</script>
```

Data property in Roster.vue

```js
data() {
  return {
    loading: false,
    // vars in data instead of computed because the watcher needs to change the value
    rosterData: this.$store.getters.getRosterData,
    selectedSeason: this.$store.getters.getSiteOptions.activeSeason
  }
},
```

So I'm grabbing the data from my store. I'm not seeing an issue when refreshing on the /roster page

player//
Directory Structure

```
|pages
|_player
|__ _id
|__ _name
|___index.vue
```

index.vue

```html
<template>
  <Player :data="data" :photos="photos"></Player>
</template>

<script>
import Player from '~/components/Player.vue'
import { refreshStore } from '~/utility/refreshStore.js'

export default {
  components: {
    Player,
  },

  async asyncData({ params, $axios, $config, store }) {
    try {
      const id = params.id

      // If the page is refreshed, the store is not available. If that's the case, make an axios call to get data
      if (!store.getters.getStoreActive) {
        await refreshStore(params, $axios, $config, store)
      }

      const data = await $axios.$get($config.apiUrl + '/players?id=' + id)

      const photos = await $axios.$get(
        $config.apiUrl +
          '/photos?playerId=' +
          id +
          '&limit=' +
          store.getters.getSiteOptions.limitPlayerPagePhotos +
          '&season=' +
          store.getters.getSiteOptions.activeSeason,
      )

      return { data, photos }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('in error of async')
      console.log(error)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I have a function `refreshStore` that will repopulate the store when you go directly to a player// page or when you refresh on that page. This works on my local when I run nuxt generate then nuxt start, but it once deployed, I get a 404 instead

Full directory

[image]

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: @kissu I'm actually seeing my 1st issue on my local, but not the 2nd

Comment: So you're using a module for Amp? Could you share some configuration here please?

Comment: @kissu No I'm not using the amp CLI. I'll add my nuxt.config.js file. I actually fixed the 1st issue. I had the setting trailingSlash set to false with some middleware that I'm pretty sure was causing the first issue

Comment: I'm noticing that a refresh on a route like /articles throws a 301 redirect to /articles/ then it goes back to /articles and works fine. On a page like /articles/<id>, it does not 301 after a refresh

Comment: Do you have a [repro] of your code and could you please update your question with your latest discoveries. It's not very clear as of right now.

Comment: For debugging purposes, can you please host your app on https://app.netlify.com/drop and see if you still have the issue there? Will help us debug from where the issue is coming from.

Comment: @kissu https://gracious-leavitt-e8523a.netlify.app I still see the same issue when going to any page with an <id> and hitting refresh. I get a 404.

Comment: Alright, there is indeed something strange here. Can you please give all the info about, let's say `roster`? The component mainly and maybe something else related that you find relevant, like the navbar.

Comment: @kissu I'm thinking the issue is I'm not generating the pages with subdirectories. I'll edit my question with details on the roster and player pages

Comment: I'm not sure to properly understand your structure of `player`, can you either link a screenshot of your directories in your code editor or even better, share a github repo? Here, it looks like `_id` and `_name` are nested at the same level.

Comment: @kissu Just added an image. That was a typo

Comment: What is that `player\_id\_name` syntax? `\` is an escape char, not a directory one. Your directory should look like something like this: https://i.imgur.com/hUwWP9L.png

Comment: @kissu It's just different syntax. Still produces the same result. I'm still seeing the error when updating to your syntax

Comment: It maybe produces the same result but it's not because it's the same thing, it just somehow fallbacks gracefully. It maybe does not on Heroku btw. Please follow the conventions. Also, what do you have in your `_id.vue` component? Also, try to not mix `yarn install` and `npm run generate` at the same time, this may produce some strange behavior too. Do you have a github repo for this or is it private?

Comment: Here is the git repo: https://github.com/ajohnson10209/eagle-nuxt. I just updated my pages @kissu

Comment: I'll see if I can give it a look! In the meantime, why are you importing components like `import Player from '~/components/Player.vue'` while having `components: true` in your `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: You do need some `.env` variables to make it run I guess? Are they private or public for the most?

Comment: @kissu thanks for all your help! Honestly that was an oversight

Comment: yes you do need them. I can share it to you but can we do it outside of stackoverflow? @kissu

Answer (score 0):

Add redirect rules in the AWS amplify.

[image: Check this SS]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just found this answer which was promising

https://www.appsloveworld.com/vuejs/100/17/nuxtjs-dynamic-routes-doesnt-work-on-page-reload-after-deploying-as-a-spa-on-aws

Basically, it says:

Go to "Rewrites and redirects" -> Edit
Source address: </^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
Targe address: /index.html
Type: 200 (Rewrite)

But this made me run into more problems...
And I found the good answer here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3829

I deleted all rules, and now it's working...